# How to check std::type_info with Google Test?

Tags: c++, googletest

Having `std::any` in some classes, I'm looking for a good approach for a unit test checking if the contained value has the correct type. Because there are a lot of such test cases, I'm willing to introduce a custom matcher or macro.

Here are some approaches I tried:

```cpp
std::any x = 73;
EXPECT_THAT(x.type(), Eq(typeid(double)));
```

does not compile, saying `error: ‘std::type_info::type_info(const std::type_info&)’ is private within this context` (is not copyable).

```cpp
std::any x = 73;
EXPECT_EQ(x.type(), typeid(double));
```

works, but results in following message, which is not very readable:

```
Expected equality of these values:
  x.type()
    Which is: 16-byte object <D8-11 5F-DB 75-7F 00-00 54-F5 57-DB 75-7F 00-00>
  typeid(double)
    Which is: 16-byte object <D8-11 5F-DB 75-7F 00-00 93-F5 57-DB 75-7F 00-00>
```

```cpp
std::any x = 73;
EXPECT_THAT(x.type().name(), Eq(typeid(double).name()));
```

gives a much better error message (see below), but I'd prefer comparing types, not type names.

```
Value of: x.type().name()
Expected: is equal to 0x7f2a6317f593 pointing to "d"
  Actual: 0x7f2a6317f554 pointing to "i" (of type char const*)
```

Could a custom matcher help here? Ideally I'd like to have something like

```cpp
EXPECT_THAT(x.type(), IsOfType(typeid(double)));
```

or

```cpp
EXPECT_TYPE_EQ(x.type(), typeid(double));
```

checking the type and giving a more or less readable error message in case it fails.

Or do you think this is overpedantic and simply comparing type names is a more pragmatic approach?

Comment: there is `any_cast`, it throws an exception when the type differ, though it also compares `type_id`s internally. Erasing the type is what `std::any` does. You need runtime information to restore the information on the type

Comment: I don't know much about google test, but can't you write a thin wrapper around `std::type_info` that compares equality correctly but prints as a pretty strung?

Comment: It seems that new GoogleTest versions have pretty-printer for `std::type_info` (including demangling) out of the box: https://godbolt.org/z/984c4ooGc - so one solution is to upgrade your library version.

Comment: Just provide `void PrintTo(const std::type_info&, std::ostream*)`.

Comment: @MarekR Not really, ADL won't find it. GTest doc says pretty clearly that it has to be in the same namespace as the class that you are trying to print.

Comment: Anyway It works for me out of the box, no extra code is needed https://godbolt.org/z/3c6Kq3r1c so consider upgrading your gtest library.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped me. I wasn't aware that I was using such an old Google Test version (I'm still using Ubuntu 22.04 which comes with Google Test 1.11 by default). Happy to hear that the problem disappears simply by upgrading.

Comment: @MarekR: Thanks, that also worked, but I had to put the `PrintTo` function inside `namespace std`, just like @Yksisarvinen said. Not beautiful, but might be a workaround for someone who cannot upgrade Google Test to a newer version.

Comment: Adding anything to `std` namespace what is not allowed by standard is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std). So upgrading gtest is better solution.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I believe another option would be to use `MATCHER_P` macro, e.g. this way: https://godbolt.org/z/z9n1d6Yne